# Select for editing cell in jtable

Tags: java, jtable

i want to create a method for set the pointer in an especific cell of the jtable, for start editing in this cell automatic with the keyboard, but i don´t know who is the method, someone know the process?[image: example image]

for example when i read a barcode that a especific cell start the pointer in the cell, i tried to set the focus with `changeSelection(x,y,bool,bool);` but this does not work

Comment: This is really too broad for StackOverflow, you should tell us what you have tried so far and what the specific problem is.

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach using `editCellAt()`.